# Linked in picture-url

Tags: linkedin-api

If anyone know if the Linkedin Rest api picture-url for user is permanent or it is temporary? Samething goes for the userid, it feels that userid is totally different when I do a request in my mobile application and when I do a request via the linked in rest api tool.

Comment: I am using  this api  -  v1/people/~/network/updates/  and picture is under 

['updateContent'] ['person']['pictureUrl'] , i hope it can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture URL is relative the the image that is currently being used. If a member changes their picture, so will the URL.

The member id is linked to your specific application.  Different applications will return a different id for a member.